# Stripping white space between characters in a word

Tags: python, string

so I am first removing all special characters and punctuation.

Then trying to strip white space between characters in words.

```
input_str = 'strength and honor performance, i/n. c'
input_str = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', input_str)
```

Result:
It's giving me a space after removing dot(.) because of the extra whitespace between `n.  c`

```
strength and honor performance in c
```

Desired Result:

```
strength and honor performance inc
```

How does the program know that `i/n. c` is `inc` and not `in c`?

I only want to remove all whitespace associated after dot(.) or comma (,) and the dot(.) or comma(,) itself.

I tried the strip method, but that only removes leading and trailing whitespaces.

Comment: What is the difference between the space `"strength and"` and `"n. c"`?

Comment: So you want to remove the space between "i/n. c" but not between "strength and?" This decision seems to require context but regex doesn't really do context. Would you describe, in greater detail, which whitespace characters should be removed?

Comment: To ask a different way: How does the program know that `i/n. c` is `inc` and not `in c`?

Comment: There is no way of solving this without involving more advance methods (nlp or something of that sort) unless you know that this only applies for this particular pattern (in. c) or known set of patterns

Comment: _I only want to remove all whitespace associated after dot(.) or comma (,) and the dot(.) or comma(,) itself_ so do that.  That pattern is `[.,] +`.